# Find account address given public key

Tags: onflow-cadence

Is there a command on the Flow CLI that will allow me to input a public key and the command will output the account address associated with that key?

`flow accounts get <public key> --network mainnet --output json`

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible given how keys work on Flow.
You can add a public key to any number of accounts, so it wouldn't be able to return a specific address.